# Trying to echo a Javascript procedure in PHP but it returns nothing

Tags: javascript, php

I have the below code which uses JS procedure to format a date into May 6, 2012 which then will be echoed in PHP code:

```
<script>
var day_one="2012-05-06";
var monthNames = [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
    "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ];

function Disp_DayOne (DayOne) {
var parts = DayOne.split("-");
return monthNames[parts[1]-1]+"&nbsp;"+parts[2]+","+"&nbsp;"+parts[0];  
}
</script>

<?php echo '<script>Disp_DayOne(day_one);</script>'?>
```

I need the JS procedure to format the date and display it within PHP but it returns nothing !!
I would highly thank and appreciate any help !!

Comment: There is client side and server side

Comment: Take a look at the DateTime class. There's no need to involve javascript for this. One or the other.

Comment: PHP runs on the server. It prints out exactly what you typed. On the client side, it runs the function - but that function does not amend the HTML in any way to "print" anything. It appears that you need to back up and focus on the difference between client-side and server-side processing.

Comment: You know you can display the date directly with javascript. You don't need PHP echo to do that. And if you love PHP so much and you just want to do it that way than the best approach is to do ajax call to PHP file sending the data and let PHP file receive the data and display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code would just call the method. How would you know if it returns anything or not? You're not displaying the result. You're just writing `<script>Disp_DayOne(day_one);</script>` to the document.

You could use `document.write` to display the results:

```
echo '<script>document.write(Disp_DayOne(day_one)); </script> ';
```

Comment: Thank you Comodo and Mr. Singh  your answers worked for me !! . Thank you very much to all of you brothers for helping me out. I am really owing a lot to this wonderful stack overflow !!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to output the result of your function just try

```
<script>
document.write(Disp_DayOne(day_one))
</script>
```

Also, as other mentioned here, you need to understand simple client and server sides logic